# Python - basemap.contourf produces blank map

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

i'm trying to plot some data on a map using mpl_toolkits.basemap lib.
I almost got it right, but the map comes blank when run the script:

[Map I get from the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jirSW.png)

My guess is that the contourf cannot find the levels on the array, here is the data i'm using:

[values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMAd0.png)

And the code to the actual call to contourf, where *data* is the array:

```
baseMap = Basemap(width=7000000, height=8500000, resolution='l', projection='stere', lat_0=-23.5166, lon_0=-60.11694, lat_ts=-23.5166)

baseMap.drawcountries()
baseMap.drawcoastlines()
baseMap.drawmapboundary()

baseMap.drawmeridians(np.arange(180., 360.,10.))
baseMap.drawparallels(np.arange(0., 90, 10.))

clevs = [0,1,2.5,5,7.5,10,15,20,30,40,50,70,100,150,200,250,300,400,500,600,750]

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(loncorners, latcorners)

cs = baseMap.contourf(xx, yy, data[0][:][:])
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of your data / make it a reproducible example ?

Comment: Don't you have to add you `clevs` as argument to `countourf`?

Comment: @grovina the data comes from a netcdf file, is way to long to add a sample here and they don't have a pattern, so i don't think it is possible to make it reproducible. The only way i found to show the data was that screenshot.

Comment: @armatita It is not necessary, clevs would just change the label next to the map.

Comment: i'm getting this when debugging: contour.py:1534: UserWarning: Warning: converting a masked element to nan. self.zmax = float(z.min())

Comment: Please be aware that you cannot expect anyone to look deeper into the issue, if there is no [mcve] provided. Supposingly the problem does not depend on the exact data file in use, so such a [mcve] would just include some fake data to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates are in the data format, not in the basemap format. 
You forgot this:

```
x, y = baseMap(xx, yy)
```

So after addind that, change the following line to:

```
cs = baseMap.contourf(x, y, data[0][:][:])
```

And it should work.